# What's wrong with these two functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-animate

I'm tryin to use these two functions. Am I allowed to use `.more .open` and `.more .close`, cause they do not work as expected.

I tried also the `.hasClass("open")` / `.hasClass("close")` but nothing.

```
$(".more .open").on("click", function() {
  $("#wait").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, function() {
    $(".more").toggleClass("nascosto"), $("#wait").toggleClass("hidden")
  });
});

$(".more .close").on("click", function() {
  $(".more").toggleClass("nascosto"), $("#wait").toggleClass("hidden")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not correct. It should have been as `.more.open`. Please check the following snippet:

```js
$(".more.open").on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more open">
     more open div
 </div>
```